# How could i fill fields of pop up windows with Selenium?

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm working with Selenium extension for Firefox trying to fill fields for one project of the university for Facebook but I can not access to a specific window (promote website) on a page created by me on that social network, because appears an error with the following message:

```
Element id = fbpage.... not found
```

I don't know if it's because this is a pop up window or something similar.
Someone knows how could I access to that kind of field?

I add the html code version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.facebook.com/admgsproject" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
  <td>open</td>
  <td>/</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>click</td>
  <td>link=Facebook</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>click</td>
  <td>link=Facebook</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>click</td>
  <td>css=#navItem_811212168953432 &gt; div &gt; div.clearfix &gt; a._5afe.sortableItem &gt; div.linkWrap.noCount &gt; span</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>click</td>
  <td>css=#navItem_811212168953432 &gt; div &gt; div.clearfix &gt; a._5afe.sortableItem &gt; div.linkWrap.noCount &gt; span</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>click</td>
  <td>id=fbpage_invite_audience_action</td>  //ERROR
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>click</td>
  <td>id=fbpage_invite_audience_action</td>  //ERROR
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>click</td>
  <td>//div[@id='u_jsonp_3_2']/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>click</td>
  <td>//div[@id='u_jsonp_3_2']/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

The part where i can not access is the html code that have invite_audience_action

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Kindly share web drive code and html code..

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the selectWindow command?
https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-tips-working-with-multiple-windows